# app is moving slow when dynamically generating buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I want to build an news app for iOS where each article is split into categories and displayed in a table view. So if an article has 2 categories(Ex: coding and programming) then the cell that displays this article should also have 2 buttons, one for each category. If i add the buttons without text then the table view works well. But if I add a title to the buttons then after a few scrolls the app begins to lag.

**This is the code for generating the buttons:**

```
func createHashtagButtonsWith(var categories categories: Array<JSON>, cell: ExploreTableViewCell)
{

    var x: CGFloat = 0;
    var y: CGFloat = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < hashtags.count; i++){
        let size = categories[i].stringValue.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13.0)]);

        if (x + size.width + 16 > cell.categoryView.frame.size.width){
            x = 0;
            y = size.height + 10;
            cell.categoryView.frame.size.height = cell.categoryView.frame.size.height + size.height + 12;
        }

        let categoryButton : UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: size.width + 16, height: size.height + 8));
       categoryButton.setTitle("\(categories[i].stringValue)", forState: .Normal);
        categoryButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatBlueColorDark();
        categoryButton.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        categoryButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3;

        cell.categoryView.addSubview(categoryButton);
        x += size.width + 24;
    }
}
```

I call this method from tableView willDisplayCell

Also I have used some tips from this [perfect smooth scrolling in uitableviews](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5#.odyya16qh) article to enhance the table view

Any idea why when I add a title to the button the apps begins to lag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call this code in `willDisplayCell`, you are adding the two buttons again and again to the same cells when they are reused, so after a few scrolls you have tens of buttons in each cell.

Create the buttons in the cells themselves (on `awakeFromNib` or so) to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you, I was working on this for the last couple of days. Can you tell how could I instantiate a cell property before the awakeFromNib is called?
Basically i receive the categories from the server and I need to send the categories array in the cell object. Thanks again.

Comment: You don't need to set it before the awakeFromNib, that's for initializing the UI of the cell - keep the data separated from the cells in an array in your ViewController, and then set the data for the right row in the cell that will be displayed at that row in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

Comment: If i do this how will I know how many buttons i need to add in the cell? The number of button can be different from article to article and the button frame depends on the length of the title.

Comment: Then at least you should remove the old buttons before adding the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to add the buttons in willDisplayCell and to remove all buttons for that cell in didEndDisplayingCell. Basically the problem was that every time the cell will display i was adding the buttons and i will have a lot of buttons stack one of top of the other for each cell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let tableCell = cell as! ExploreTableViewCell;
    let subviews = tableCell.hashtagsView.subviews;
    // todo: should replace with a for in
    for (var i = 0; i < subviews.count; i++) {
        if(subviews[i].isKindOfClass(UIButton)){
            subviews[i].removeFromSuperview();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks TheEye for the help.